# Скомпилировать js в ts

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typescript

Всем привет, пишу проект на nestJs, случайно перетёр файлы , осталась только папка dist с js файлами, как я могу декомпилировать их обратно в ts ?

Comment: попробуй https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-to-ts-converter  , но мне кажется по большей части это невозможно

Comment: Понял ,буду пробовать, спасибо.

Comment: Хороший повод использоать git, чтобы можно было откатывать изменения

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin да даже некоторые IDE хранят историю и позволяют откатываться....например в PHPStorm. У верен у JetBrains все продукты так умеют....так что даже гит не нужен. Но в целом да.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Они же вроде хранят историю существующих файлов и вернуть удаление вроде можно только до перезагрузки

Comment: @EzioMercer первое не помню точно. второе и после перезагрузки работает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Поверю на слово)

Comment: Кстати, если файлы просто удалились и не сильно многое изменилось с того времени, то можете воспользоваться всякими программами в зависимоти от вашей ОС для восстановления файлов